# How CiviCRM works when a url hits

Tags: evaluating-civicrm, civicrm-home

I am new to CiviCRM. I just want to know how the back end process works in CiviCRM when a URL hits in browser.

Ex. http://localhost/test/drupal/civicrm/member?reset=1

When I am running this URL in browser what are the .tpl and php,js,css files are running

Also I don't have previous knowledge in CMS Coding and Extentions, Is there a step by step guide to understand CiviCRM

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you are looking for [CiviCRM documentation](https://docs.civicrm.org)

There you will find:

- [CiviCRM developer guide](https://docs.civicrm.org/dev/en/latest) - probably the most relevant place to start for you
- [CiviCRM administrator guide](https://wiki.civicrm.org/confluence/display/CRMDOC/Installation+and+Upgrades)
- [CiviCRM user guide](https://docs.civicrm.org/user/en/latest)

In the Developer Guide you'll find pages like [Codebase & Architecture](https://docs.civicrm.org/dev/en/latest/core/architecture/) which are a good starting point for your initial question.

CiviCRM Stack Exchange (this site!) is a great place to ask specific questions, and you should also join the CiviCRM community over on [CiviCRM chat](https://chat.civicrm.org).